# CSS not applied to small screen size mobile

Tags: css

Display different logo according to the screen size, don't know why the mobile (Sony Ericsson WT19i) with size at 320 cannot perform the correct stylesheet.

I check the screen width using javascript window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight which is 320x401. It load the CSS for 800px.

```
@media screen {
body  {
        background-image:url('desktop.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    body  {
        background-image:url('320P.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    body {
        background-image:url('800P.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale:1.0" />` to your `<head>`.

Comment: Add javascript here and better use `max-width`, because in `max-device-width` you must add `device-pixel-ratio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why this is happening??**

because css by default takes the last rules applied in its style for any tags....so :

`@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px)` and

`@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px)` 
they both apply to the `width of 320px`...but since you have mentioned `max-device-width: 800px` later, browser ignores `max-device-width: 320px` rule as it can be overwritten by last rule and hence applies the last rule.

**Solution**

Either swap the order or use `min-device-width: 321px` instead of `max-device-width: 800px`!

**demo** : i have use `min-width` to show demo, use `min-device-width` for your css

[**demo of what you are doing**](http://jsfiddle.net/78vJv/1/)

[**solution 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/78vJv/2/) (*swapped queries*)

[**solution 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/78vJv/3/) (*use **min** instead of **max** to avoid overwrite*)

Answer (score 1):

Change this :-

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 321px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px){
    body {
        background-image:url('800P.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the order of your media queries. You want the smaller screens to overide the larger so they have to be defined after:

```
@media screen {
body  {
        background-image:url('desktop.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    body {
        background-image:url('800P.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    body  {
        background-image:url('320P.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-attachment:fixed !important;
        background-position:right bottom !important; 
    }
}
```

Also, remove all of the `!important` . There is absolutely no reason to have them there

Answer (score 0):

invert the order for the last 2 media